# Using a Map with GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, dictionary

I'm doing an assignment where we have to use mapping with GUI to do a simple Country and Capital search.  The user inputs the Country, and Capital, then pushes the add button and it adds those to the map. After being added, they can search for the Country with the search box.  It's hinted at that I should use a Map instance to store the values, and to name that instance countries. Once the user inputs the Country they are searching for in the search field, it will highlight that countries capital amongst the other capitals in the list on the right.  I'm very lost on how to begin this. I have the gui complete, but the coding behind the other part is what baffles me, I'm not sure how to begin.

This is what my gui looks like. [image]

Also, how do I get rid of those Item 1, Item 2 and so on by default?

Any help is appreciated, I'm just really stuck right now.

Comment: Show your code, what you have done so far.

Comment: What's the point of having a `JList` if you only want to display one item? Will you keep adding countries to the list every time the user searches?

Comment: All I've done is generated code, creating the gui, it's too long to be posted I figure.

Comment: That's not what your description says. Your desription says that the user inputs the key and value into the map, and when the user searches, the result will be added to the list. Maybe you should clarify that your post. Also do you know how to use a Map?

Comment: Also what do you want displayed in the list exactly? How do you want the details displayed? Just country? Just capital? Both?

Comment: If i'm not wrong, you just want to add many countries and their capital cities and search only one of them and display in that area.
All this to be done with HashMap thing.

Comment: Sorry I was confused, in the search field you will enter a country, and it will highlight its capital in the list. Only the capital is displayed in the list, all other capital's will still be visible, but the one you searched for will be highlighted.

Comment: Yeah, we haven't really learned too much about mapping, so I don't understand it.

Comment: @Tonno22 Why do you want to display all cities and highlight only the searched one? Showing only the required city would be enough.

Comment: It's just how the assignment is supposed to be done I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for example. Try calling these method where your action is performed

```
public class hashMap {

    HashMap<String, String> hashMap;
    public hashMap(){
        hashMap=new HashMap<String,String>();
    }
    public void insert(String country,String city){
        hashMap.put(country, city);
    }
    public String get(String key){
        return hashMap.get(key);  //this will return the city of the country
    }
}
```

and for JTextArea, set it as empty. Then display using .setText(get(counrty)); method like shown.

Comment: So I have two different input textfields, one is countryInput, and one is capitalInput, how can I make what the user inputs in those fields be inserted into the map? I believe that is what I have to do is it not?

Comment: Oh, so my add button is my actionperformed, and it will take the two values entered in the different fields and add them to the map.

Comment: @Tonno22 through actionListener get two strings separately that is country and city. Once you are done with it pass both strings in this method. It will be added in the hashMap then

Comment: @Tonno22 Highlighting the city means that you just have to change the color of the text of the city when its country is searched. Simple

Comment: Take a string variable and use it in actionPerformed like variable=getText();

Comment: private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String text = countryInput.getText();
    String text2 = capitalInput.getText();
    }

Comment: Could we continue this into private chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50892/discussion-between-user2382867-and-tonno22)